# How can I force Network Manager to associate to a specific access point?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

in my network environment I have two access points with the same ESSID; one of them is near my desktop and another is in another building.

I get signal from both of them, and the connection often switches from the near one to the far one, leading to a connection drop.

How can I force network manager to use only a given AP, ignoring the other?

Answer (score 18):

First, find the BSSID (MAC address) of the AP that's further away. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40068/show-bssid-of-an-access-point/40070#40070) on how to get it.

Then click on the NM indicator → choose *Edit Connections...* → then click on the *Wireless* tab. Find the SSID in the list and click on *Edit*.

Now rename the connection to make it easier tell them apart and untick the *Connect automatically* checkbox. Also enter the address of the AP in the *BSSID* field.

[image]
<sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/647404.png))</sub>

That's it. You'll still see both APs in the NM indicator with the same name (don't know if you can change that), but your computer will only automatically connect to the closer one.

Comment: Hi, in my case I try to avoid a 00:00:00:00:00:00 bssid AP, but the editing window you talk about doesn't let me enter that value. Can I do it some other way?  Thanks.

Comment: This still seems to work for Ubuntu 20.04, but I had to turn the wireless off and then on again for it to switch access points. Also, you can use `nmcli dev wifi` to see which access point you're connected to.

Answer (score 0):

With kudus to @htorque, which showed me what to do, I still do not recommend changing the name of the connection. Also, setting the correct BSSID should be easy with a modern Network Manager UI - it will show you which BSSIDs are available and what's their signal strength - for example, here's Plasma's network connection editor:

[image: Plasma Network Connections editor shows BSSID list]

After selecting the correct BSSID, you may need to disconnect and reconnect (if it is currently connected to the wrong one).

From the command line, you can run `nmcli device wifi` (or just `nmcli d w`) to list all the access points around and their BSSIDs.

You can also temporarily connect to another BSSID from the command line by running `nmcli connection up CONNECTION-NAME ap BSSID`, or set the BSSID in the connection configuration using `nmcli connection modify CONNECTION-NAME wifi.bssid BSSID`

Hint: use the TAB key to help you complete command words - it is a lot of fun not needing to type exactly all those things.