# Show BSSID of an access point?

Tags: wireless

I want to get the BSSID for a known SSID, how can I do that? Thanks :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/222549/get-mac-address-of-accesspoint

Answer (score 16):

If I'm not mistaken, it should be the *Address* shown when issuing

```
sudo iwlist scanning
```

E.g.:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:11:22:33:44:55
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"the_known_ssid"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    ...
```

Comment: small addition to htorque: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning|grep Address` will show only the adresses. My post will take more time so htorques' is better ;-)

Answer (score 10):

If using network manager (the default in Ubuntu), you can use `nmcli`. It also has several options for the output format.

In your case, where you know the SSID and want the BSSID :

```
nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,ACTIVE dev wifi list | grep $wanted_ssid
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also install wifi-radar which will give you a graphical list of all wireless networks your NIC is seeing.  Use `sudo apt-get install wifi-radar` to install it.

Answer (score 2):

nm-tool | grep Wireless-Name where you gotta replace "Wireless-Name" for the wireless you are trying to connect to will give you all the info you need

Answer (score 1):

[aircrack-ng](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/aircrack-ng)  can do this.

`sudo airmon-ng start eth1 6` to use eth1 to monitor channel 6 (the channel is optional) and then you can use `sudo airodump-ng eth1` to make it show you the BSSID.