# Get MAC address of a network access point

Tags: wireless

How can I find out what the MAC address (BSSID) of the wireless access point I'm connected to is?

Comment: Though this question has been marked as a duplicate, the accepted answer here is what gave me the info I needed. The highest ranked answer on the linked question gives me more info than I need, which didn't let me figure out which of the two MAC addresses my printer was listing belonged to the SSID my laptop is connected to. If there's ever a cleanup of duplicates, perhaps the answers can be merged?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any of these 3 works:

- `arping 192.168.0.1`  Change the IP adress to whatever you use. The MAC address is in the reply between brackets.
- `iwconfig | grep "Access Point"`. Access point will be colored and behind it the MAC address.
- `iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Address` same as previous command (color etc).

Comment: `iwlist wlan0 scan|grep` worked, thank you a lot :)

Comment: The `iwlist` option gives me a message saying the interface doesn't support scanning; the `arping` option gives me what is probably a cached version of the wired connection I unplugged. Happily, the `iwconfig` option gives me the info I needed.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using a recent desktop version of Ubuntu (with interfaces managed by `network-manager`) then `nmcli` is a more configurable option than `nm-tool`. For example, to list some common information including SSID, access point MAC (BSSID), channel frequency, signal strength etc. for all the access points seen by the active wifi device you can use

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

You can limit the output to specific fields e.g. to see just the access point MAC addresses (BSSIDs) and connection status, use

```
nmcli -f BSSID,ACTIVE dev wifi list
```

To return just the MAC address to which the wifi device is currently connected (i.e. the access point whose ACTIVE field is 'yes'), you can use

```
nmcli -f BSSID,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk '$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}'
```

Comment: Use `-f SSID,BSSID,ACTIVE` to also show SSIDs