# How do I get the MAC address of my router?

Tags: command-line, networking

Is there a Linux command that allows me to get the MAC address of my router?

Comment: which one? your router should have multiple mac addresses for both sides of communication (incoming / outgoing).

Comment: Should this go in Super User?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like one-liners:

```
arping -f -I $(ip route show match 0/0 | awk '{print $5, $3}')
```

`arping` shows the MAC associated with the default gateway IP address from the output of `ip route show match 0/0`, parsed by `awk`.

Comment: I tried this (and other answers). They give good info, but the MAC address shown was off by two digits from what I was looking for. My printer lists two routers with the same SSID (probably guest and regular), and wants me to pick by MAC address. This answer https://askubuntu.com/a/222553 gives me one of the two listed, with the `iwconfig | grep "Access Point"` command. I think the one that was off by two was the cached version of the wired connection, which I unplugged to try to make sure I was getting the wireless route.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use the obsoleted commands `ifconfig`(8), `arp`(8) or `route`(8).  Use the new command that replace them and can do more, `ip`(8).

Use `ip route list` to see which `default` router your machine have.  That should be a line wich starts with `default` (or `0.0.0.0`) and have the IP address to the router after.  If you uses IPv6, just add the `-6` switch, `ip -6 route list`.

```
default via 192.168.11.1 dev eth0  proto static
```

To see the MAC address of the `default` routers IP address, use `ip neigh` and look up the line with the IP address and MAC address after `lladdr`.e

```
192.168.11.1 dev eth0 lladdr 1c:af:f7:XX:XX:XX REACHABLE
```

If you don't find a machine in the list, you need to connect to it, because it has been removed from the list because not used for a while.  So just try:

```
ping -c 3 192.168.11.1
```

Then try the `ip neigh` command again. The option `-c 3` will restrict `ping` to only send three `ICMP ECHO` messages and then end.  If not set, it will run until you stop the program with `C-c`.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't know the IP of your router, it's most likely your gateway which you can get [from the `route` command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-gateway-ip-address/):

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Note the line with the flags `UG`. The address in the `Gateway` column of that line is what you're looking for. Then follow [2707974's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/605307/25755) with `arp -n` (ping the IP if it doesn't show up at first), and find the matching line:

```
$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.1              ether   00:11:22:33:44:55   C                     eth0
192.168.0.2              ether   66:77:88:99:aa:bb   C                     eth0
```

Here, your router's MAC would be `00:11:22:33:44:55`.

Comment: The corresponding one-liner: ``arp -n | grep `route -n | awk '/UG/{print $2}'` | awk '{print $3}'``

Answer (score 5):

Here is one-liner which works in `dash`, `bash` and `zsh`:

```
ip neigh|grep "$(ip -4 route list 0/0|cut -d' ' -f3) "|cut -d' ' -f5|tr '[a-f]' '[A-F]'
```

1. `ip -4 route list 0/0` returns something like:

> default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 100

2. we get IP from that line as third field with `cut` and grep line containing that IP and immediate space after it from the output of network neighborhood. (space is required to avoid matching of `192.168.0.1` with `192.168.0.10`), the matched line would be something like:

> 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 lladdr ca:fe:ba:be:be:af REACHABLE

3. Now we get fifth field and make it uppercase:

> CA:FE:BA:BE:BE:AF

Comment: A bit more explanation would help the rest of us understand your script!

Comment: For the last line there's a Bash feature that expands a variable to upper case: `echo ${info[5]^^}`

Comment: @DavidFoerster I wanted to write a portable command but the original variant relied on array indexing specific to zsh (from one) so I've updated the answer with the variant portable between three most popular shells

Answer (score 2):

Is not a complete solution, but you check arp -n.

```
ddd@mmm ~ $ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx          ether   00:e0:1e:b4:12:42   C                     eth0
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy          ether   00:14:78:52:28:d2   C                     wlan0
```

Comment: Doesn't this get the MAC address of the interfaces on the computer, not the router?

Comment: If you ping your router (say `ping 192.168.0.1`) you should then have its MAC address on the arp cache...

Comment: thanks @2707974 but I don't khnow no mac address no address ip and I want have a command that give me only the ip adress or mac adress of my router because I want to use the command in a script python for that show all arp table is not useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is an improved version of Grief's answer. It is possible for ip -4 route list 0/0 to return more than one line (IP), in which case the complete one liner doesn't work. So the following modified version only uses the first line that ip -4 route list 0/0 returns.

```
ip neigh|grep "$(ip -4 route list 0/0|head -1|cut -d' ' -f3) "|cut -d' ' -f5|tr '[a-f]' '[A-F]'
```