# Roaming not working lost for 5 seconds wifi connection intel 7260 on the thinkpad t440p only when there are multiple AP ruckus + zonedirector

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have disconnections every 5/10/20 min random from WiFi only when I'm in a space where there are multiple AP(Ruckus + Zonedirector) with the same SSID.

When there is only one AP(Ruckus) is stable.

it's look like the roaming is not working properly.

tried different ubuntu version 12.04 and now 14.10 current
with Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)

`lshw:
*-network 
  version: 83
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.0.4-040004-generic firmware=23.15.10.0 ip=192.168.11.62 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:33 memory:e0400000-e0401fff`

tried different kernel from the 3.15 , 3.16 and 3.19 and now 4.0.4 current
tried different firmware iwlwifi from 22.24.8.0 to the 22.228.9 ,25.17.12  and the current 23.15.10 
tried different change the  `iwlwifi.conf`  with  `11n_disable=1`  or   `bt_coex_active=0`  or  `iwconfig wlan0 retry short 21`

I set `Power Management:off` with `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf 
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1`

from syslog:

`wpa_supplicant[1152]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
wpa_supplicant[1152]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
kernel: [13865.409620] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by  MAC_AP_RUCKUS2
NetworkManager[1115]  (wlan0): disconnecting for new activation request.
NetworkManager[1115]:  (wlan0): device state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'none') [100 30 0]
NetworkManager[1115]:  (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
NetworkManager[1115]:  (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 10294
kernel: [14182.706161] wlan0: deauthenticating from MAC_AP_RUCKUS2 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
wpa_supplicant[1152]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=MAC_AP_RUCKUS2 reason=3 locally_generated=1`

dmesg:

`wlan0: deauthenticating from MAC_AP_RUCKUS2 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: IN
cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IN
cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
wlan0: authenticate with MAC_AP_RUCKUS
wlan0: send auth to MAC1 (try 1/3)
wlan0: authenticated
RX AssocResp from MAC_AP_RUCKUS (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
wlan0: associated
cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: GB
wlan0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by MAC_AP_RUCKUS
cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)`

`iw event -f`  :

`wlan0 (phy #0): disconnected (local request)
phy #0: regulatory domain change: set to world roaming by the wireless core upon initialization request
regulatory domain change: set to IN by a user request
wlan0 (phy #0): scan started
wlan0 (phy #0): scan finished: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5745 5765 5785 5805 5825, ""
wlan0: new station MAC_RUCKUS_1
wlan0 (phy #0): auth MAC_RUCKUS_1 -> MAC_RUCKUS_2 status: 0: Successful [frame: b0 00 3c 00 5c 51 4f 55 8a 7f 6c aa b3 6d 4b 1c 6c aa b3 6d 4b 1c 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00]
wlan0 (phy #0): assoc MAC_RUCKUS_1 -> MAC_RUCKUS_2 status: 0: Successful [frame: 10 00 3c 00 5c 51 4f 55 8a 7f 6c aa b3 6d 4b 1c 6c aa b3 6d 4b 1c 10 00 11 04 00 00 03 c0 01 08 8c 12 98 24 b0 48 60 6c dd 18 00 50 f2 02 01 01 81 00 03 a4 00 00 27 a4 00 00 42 43 5e 00 62 32 2f 00 2d 1a ef 01 1b ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 04 06 46 e7 0d 00 3d 16 2c 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 02 00 00 dd 08 00 13 92 01 00 01 05 00]
wlan0 (phy #0): connected to MAC_RUCKUS_1
phy #0: regulatory domain change: set to GB by a country IE request on phy0
wlan0 (phy #0): scan started
wlan0 (phy #0): scan finished: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700, ""
wlan0 (phy #0): scan started
wlan0 (phy #0): scan finished: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700, ""
wlan0 (phy #0): scan started
wlan0 (phy #0): scan finished: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700, ""
wlan0 (phy #0): scan started
wlan0 (phy #0): scan finished: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700, ""`

The only solution I have found is to go to Network Connection and set BSSID static  like here https://askubuntu.com/a/40083/78090

Comment: Each AP should have a unique name and SSID or you will have conflicts.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen  Not sure what you ask me?
I don't have any problem with same machine running windows 8,1 
In the same space other people are using windows and mac os and they have none problems with roaming or stability.